# Is there a way to compute the Poincaré dual of the following type of degree $(2n-2)$ de Rham class?

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

Given a closed, connected, symplectic manifold $(X^{2n},\omega)$, is there a systematic method to computing the Poincaré dual surface to degree $(2n-2)$ classes of the form

$$[\omega]^{n-2}\cup B + \lambda [\omega]^{n-1}$$

where $B$ is a primitive degree $2$ class, and $\lambda$ is any real scalar?  If there are only ad hoc methods, do any of you have any good sources I could go chasing?  What are some basic considerations I should have when doing this computation?

Comment: Poincare duality is linear, and sends cup product to intersection of submanifolds (when these classes are represented by submanifolds; unfortunately this is not always the case with $\Bbb Z$ coefficients!) If you can represent the Poincare duals of $[\omega]$ and $B$ by submanifolds, you can compute some intersections and get your classes that way.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeMiller.  I did know this fact about cup product corresponding to intersection of submanifolds, but what about sums of classes?

Comment: You can just deal with them separately. Like I said, Poincare duality is linear, so you have to deal with $PD([\omega]^{n-2} \smile B) + PD(\lambda [\omega]^{n-1})$. If you have $A, B \in H_2(M)$ represented by embeddings of surfaces, $A + B$ is represented by the obvious map from $A \sqcup B$. This needn't be embedded, of course, but as long as $n>1$ you can isotope them so that the self-intersection is transverse. If $n>2$ this means they're disjoint and you're done; otherwise you can modify the surface at the intersection to get something embedded representing $A+B$.

Comment: This is really helpful; thank you.

Comment: Note that cohomology classes with $\Bbb R$ coefficients are dual to homology classes with $\Bbb R$ coefficients, for which the best you can do is represent them as formal sums of submanifolds.